# Dataframe.read_sql_query() with TypeDecorator for Decimal type in SQL Alchemy

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

I have declared a table in SQLA with the custom type SqliteDecimal. I am struggling with retrieving the value into a dataframe. The return type is 'numpy.float64' where I am expecting a Decimal. I suspect the TypeDecorator is incorrect:

```
import decimal
from sqlalchemy import Column
import sqlalchemy.types as types
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import pandas as pd

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=False)
```

Decorator Class:

```
class SqliteDecimal(types.TypeDecorator):

    """Decimal decorator converts b/w decimal and text in SQLite"""
    impl = types.String

    def load_dialect_impl(self, dialect):
        return dialect.type_descriptor(types.VARCHAR(100))

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return str(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value in ["None", "NaN", "nan"]:
            result = decimal.Decimal("NaN")

        else:
            result = decimal.Decimal(value)

        return result
```

SQL Alchemy table:

```
class MyTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    number = Column(SqliteDecimal, primary_key=True)
```

Main:

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

row1 = MyTable(number=decimal.Decimal(1.1))
session.add(row1)
session.commit()
session.close()
query = session.query(MyTable)
df = pd.read_sql_query(query.statement, engine)
print(type(df.iloc[0,0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Needed coerce_float = False:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query.statement, engine, coerce_float=False)
```